# Postgres role with usage privilige but not DELETE

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres instance with a user root that has full admin privileges.

I have two databases db1 and db2.

For every database, I would like to have two users dbN_user and dbN_admin. dbN_user will be the used by my application, and dbN_admin will be used for migrations that change the table structure.

No rows are ever deleted by the application, and I would like to enforce that with user privileges.

db1_user should be able to connect to db1, and be able to `SELECT`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, but not `DELETE`.

db1_admin should have additional privileges to `DELETE`, `CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE`.

What are the SQL statements to set this up?

Comment: From what I understand, postgres can set user privileges on existing tables or on schemas, but not on databases. So I would have to create a schema, create the databases in that schema, and then grant usage permission on the schema?

Comment: That sounds about right to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dbN_admin` would be the owner of the objects, so that user would have all privileges automatically.

You need to `GRANT` the privileges for `dbN_user` on the tables and other objects themselves, not on the database.

Just add the correct `GRANT` statements after the `CREATE TABLE` statements in the SQL script that populates the database.
You need to `GRANT` the `USAGE` privilege on the schema that contains the objects to `dbN_user` as well.

There is the possibility to define *default privileges* in a database:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR dbN_admin
   GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON TABLES
   TO dbN_user;
```

This will grant the privileges automatically whenever `dbN_admin` creates a new table (but it does not affect tables created before the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` command).

Comment: Won't granting default privileges to db1_user allow it to read db2 data?

Comment: Only if `db1_admin` creates the db2 data.

Answer (score 1):

admin:

```
create user db1_admin;
create schema app_relations;
alter schema app_relations owner to db1_admin;
```

app:

```
create user db1_user;
grant CONNECT ON DATABASE db1 to db1_user; --only if you have restricted connections on db previously
grant usage on schema app_relations to db1_user;
grant select,insert,update on all tables in schema app_relations to db1_user;
```

Comment: What if db1_admin creates a new table? Will the db1_user have usage privileges automatically?

Comment: no. I you want "automatically" - use `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statement as Laurenz told